# mysql paged select from big table sorted by random-data index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I know solution when you can sort table by some unique index

```
SELECT user_id, external_id, name, metadata, date_created
FROM users
WHERE user_id > 51234123 
ORDER BY user_id ASC
LIMIT 10000;
```

but in my case, I want to sort table by some index, which have random data

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sorter` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `data1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data3` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sorter` (`sorter`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`sorter`),
  KEY `sorter_2` (`sorter`,`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

for ($i = 0; $i < 2e6; $i++)
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `t` (`sorter`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`) VALUES (rand()*3e17, rand(), rand(), rand(), rand())");

for ($i = 0; $i < 1e6; $i++)
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `t` (`sorter`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`) VALUES (0, rand(), rand(), rand(), rand())");
```

solution 1:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxId; $i += $step)

    select * from t
    where id>=$i
    order by sorter
    limit $step

select * from t order by sorter limit 512123, 10000;
10000 rows in set (9.22 sec)

select * from t order by sorter limit 512123, 1000;
1000 rows in set (6.25 sec)

+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3000000 | Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
```

solution 2:

select id from t order by sorter limit 1512123, 10000;

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | index | NULL          | sorter_2 | 16      | NULL | 1522123 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

10000 rows in set (0.74 sec)

0.74 sounds good, but for all table it takes 0.74*3000e3/10e3/60 = more than 3 minutes, and its only for gathering ids

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry fixed

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry, please check again

Answer (score 0):

Using `OFFSET` is not as efficient as you might think.  With `LIMIT 1512123, 10000`, 1512123 rows must be stepped over.  The bigger that number, the slower the query runs.

To explain the difference in the `EXPLAINs`...

'Solution 1' uses `SELECT *`; you don't have a covering index for it.  So, there are two ways the query might be run:

- (it did this):  Scan 'ALL' the table, collecting all the columns (`*`); sort; skip over 512123 rows; and deliver 10000 or 1000 rows.
- (a small `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` might lead to this):  Inside the BTree for `INDEX(sorter, id)` skip over the `OFFSET` rows; grab the `LIMIT` rows; for each grabbed row in the index, reach over into the data file using the byte offset (note: You are using MyISAM, not InnoDB) to find the row; grab `*` and deliver it.  No sort needed.

Unfortunately, the Optimizer does not have enough statistics, nor enough smarts, to always pick correctly between these two choices.

'Solution 2' uses a "covering" index `INDEX(sorter, id)`.  (The clue:  "Using index".)  This contains *all* the columns (only `sorter` and `id`) found anywhere in the query (`select id from t order by sorter limit 1512123, 10000;`), hence the index can (and usually will) be used in preference over scanning the table.

Another solution alluded to involved `where id>=$i`.  This avoids the `OFFSET`.  However, since you are using MyISAM, the index and the data cannot be "clustered" together.  With InnoDB, the data is ordered according to the `PRIMARY KEY`.  If that is `id`, then the query can start by jumping directly into the middle of the data (at `$i`).  With MyISAM, what I just described is done in the BTree for `INDEX(id)`; but it still has to bounce back and forth between that Btree and the `.MYD` file where the data is.  (This is an example of where InnoDB's design is inherently more efficient than MyISAM's.)

If your goal is to get a bunch of random rows from a table, read my [*treatise*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random).  In summary, there are faster ways, but none is 'perfect', though usually "good enough".